# Unable to call HSCAN with pattern from .Net using Stackexchange Redis

Tags: c#, redis, twemproxy

I'm trying to run the HSCAN command in Redis to match only the hash fields that are needed via C#

This is what the code looks like

```
var options = new ConfigurationOptions
{
  EndPoints = { "endpoint" },
  Proxy = Proxy.Twemproxy
 };
 twemproxy_new = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options);
 db = twemproxy_new.GetDatabase();
 Dictionary<string,string> inputDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 // populate inputDict with "n" fields & values
 var cachekey = "my_hash";
 db.GetDatabase().HashSet(cachekey, inputDict, CommandFlags.FireAndForget);

db.HashScan(cacheKey, "*9*"); 
// this is where it fails with the exception 
// Command is not available on your server: HSCAN
```

But when I run the HSCAN command on the twemproxy server it seems to work as expected

[HSCAN cache_Key 0 MATCH *pattern*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxJH5.png)

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when running [Redis on windows](https://msopentech.com/opentech-projects/redis/#), and I think it is because the StackExchange.Redis library fails to parse the Redis Version returned by the server when you are running a *beta* version, so it assumes a lower version of Redis that doesn't contains the HSCAN command.

In my case, the server is returning the following string as the Redis version:

**3.0.300-beta1**

And when SE.Redis tries to parse the version string (ResultProcessor.cs):

```
Version version;
if (Version.TryParse(val, out version))
{
    server.Version = version;
    server.Multiplexer.Trace("Auto-configured version: " + version);
}
```

Will fail to parse the version numbers, because of the **-beta1** part of the version string, being that the parameter should have the following format as stated on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1):

**major.minor[.build[.revision]]**

Try running a non beta version of redis.

I've just opened an [issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/458) about this on SE.Redis github.

Comment: Thanks 
That might be the issue
How did you decipher what the twemproxy server was returning?
I do see the version being "2.0" when I look at the multiplexer server version (which is what it's defaulting to I assume)
But I'm not sure where i'd see it as 3.0300-beta (or an equivalent)

Comment: Connect to your Redis server using **redis-cli** and run the command  **INFO SERVER**, there you should see the version string

Comment: The redis version on the server is 3.2.0. 
But for some reason SE seems to default it to 2.0 in .Net
For now got around it by doing this  

var options = new ConfigurationOptions  
{
    EndPoints = { "redis-endpoint" },
    Proxy = Proxy.None
};

Comment: Have you tried adding a default version to the config options 
            return new ConfigurationOptions
            {
                Proxy = Proxy.Twemproxy,
                AbortOnConnectFail = false,
                EndPoints = { TWEMPROXY_ADDESS },
                ,DefaultVersion = new Version(3,0,3)
            };
Didn't work for me though, still got the same error